# SSL failure while using PayPal with Payum Bundle in Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, paypal, payum

I'm currently working on a Symfony2 project with the [PayumBundle](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle) for Paypal checkouts.

I'm getting this error while trying to proceed to a payment (where the PayPal screen should be showing):

```
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Stack Trace
in /home/transhopper/vendor/kriswallsmith/buzz/lib/Buzz/Client/Curl.php at line 29
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong IMHO. Two weeks ago this was working, and I've just made minor changes that wouldn't affect PayPal operations.

I've been browsing about this error and saw that there was a SSL vulnerability called "POODLE", which made to change SSL versions but posts were like 1 year old, so I don't think it could be that issue.

Comment: It is exactly THAT issue and Paypal did a BC break by dropping the support of ssl protocol and switching completely to tls. The issue was fixed in Payum a long long time ago. What version are you using, I guess it is pretty old one?

Comment: Hi Maksim, thanks for your reply. The issue as been solved just right now! Was that we've been running an old version of PHP in our production server; dunno why it had been downgraded to an older version. Newer version installed has been installed, and error simply disapeared. Finally, there's nothing to worry about. Spasibo bolshoe.

Comment: If you will work with api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com you must use tlsv1.2, tlsv1 and tlsv1.1 doesn't work.